# content from a separate file with layout intact

Tags: html, layout, tabs

I am making a personal homepage.
I have several "categories" I would like to display.
I see two choices:

1) make many pages like category1.html, category2.html ... and
copy all the parts (such as menu, header ...) that I do not want changed.
However, it would be horrible to change all these part if I wanted to change only the layout.

2) I can put all the content in one index.html file and use tabs feature ? This would make index.html too long and I would have to look through everything to alter only the content

Is it possible to have some kind of tabs in my home page, and extract only the content of a specific div from a separate file without altering the main layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.
Actually, I think something like [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is what I want, i.e., static site generators.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you build a site using a web framework it includes a templating system that can easily handle this kind of problem. This involves a lot of stuff that might be overkill if you just want a basic HTML page.

If you just want to build some HTML pages, consider using Server Side Includes (SSI). If your webserver is Apache, this page might help: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/ssi.html

SSI lets you add tags like this

`<!--#include virtual="/header.html" -->`

That you could add to your individual categories pages so that they can share a common header.